# Laptop hangs on logout from every distro/DM tried

Tags: linux, bios

I've got a mid-spec Acer laptop (details below) that hangs when I try to log out from all the Linux distros and desktop managers I've tried. These include:

- KDE Plasma
- openSUSE Tumbleweed
- GNOME 3
- i3
- Manjaro (tried Deepin, LXDE, and GNOME)

The logout process begins, mouse pointer disappears, the majority of the windows disappear, but one or more stays behind, usually with its decorations gone. And that's it. Keyboard or trackpad generate no response. My only choice is to power-cycle it.

The specs on the laptop are:

- 8x Intel Core i5 Duo 8250U @ 1.60Hz
- 16GB RAM (2x8GB sticks, specs carefully matched)
- SSD1: Western Digital Blue 1TB
- SSD2: 256GB M2 (mfg unknown, came pre-installed)

Any idea what could be Ifhanging this machine? I'm not a hardware guru - I can install memory and hard drives, but deeper than that and I'm lost.

I just flashed the BIOS to the latest version yesterday (which required installing a Win10 partition - sigh), and no change. If you need any info from the BIOS, list it out and I'll grab it on my next reboot.

All thanks possible in advance.

Comment: This sounds like software, not a hardware issue.

Comment: But how can it be software when it occurs on vastly different distributions and desktop managers? I could see software being to blame if it was only one or two our of the list, but it's a consistent thing.

Comment: I would posit a kernel issue or graphics card driver issue common across distro, or possibly unknown hardware instruction.  I expect that if it were hardware fault Linux would not fail at a consistent point. You might want to list the model number for your Acer.